# Using path with spaces in Shell script

Tags: java, shell, unix

I am using shell script to call a java program. When calling passing java program I am passing   -Dargument which has a path to a directory. This -D argument is read from a file. Now I am facing a issue when this path contains spaces. I tried with quote and also with escaping quotes but both dint work.

Here is my shell script code, test.sh

```
   D_ARG=`(tr '\r\n' ' ' < argument.dat)
  \#executing java code by passing above argument
   java ${D_ARG} TestProgram
```

Below is my argument file, argument.dat

```
  -Dargument1="/Path /To A/File"
```

When I set the echo on using set -x, I see the shell converting it to

```
  '-Dargument1="/Path' '/To' 'A/File"'
```

Where it adds single quotes when it encounters spaces and I get "/To" class not found exception. How to resolve this issue. Any suggestion or help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ARGS=

# Do nothing if there are no spaces; if there are spaces, surround with quotes
for arg in $(perl -pe '/ / or next; s/^/"/; s/$/"/' argument.dat); do
    ARGS="$ARGS $arg";
done

java $ARGS TestProgram
```

This basically has the effect that each time a line has a space in it, it will surround with quotes, so `-Da=b c` will be turned into `"-Da=b c"`.

Note that `"-Da=b c"` is strictly equivalent to `-Da="b c"`, or even more bizarre-looking forms of it:

- `'-Da='b\ c`;
- `-D"a=b "c`;
- etc etc

The only thing which matters is that whatever characters are input field separators are escaped. Yes, this is legal:

```
alias l"l=ls"\ -l
```

Comment: But if I have more than one argument defined in the argument.dat file, then both the arguments are considered as single string, since you have specified quotes for argument "${D_ARG}"

Comment: You didn't tell that in the original question ;) In this case, your `tr` command is not the way to handle that.

Comment: Thanks fge. I used eval command in front of "java" command (eval java ${D_ARG} TestProgram) which solved my problem. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

You may possibly escape the spaces in "/Path /To A/File". This is however not a good solution, because many a times, we may formulate a command like

```
system(argv[1]);/* Example is  C specific; 
      but you understand the loop-hole imparted by single escaping.
      You may require multilevel escaping, based on your implementation. OR
      We may have to escape the string, every time it is dereferenced.
      */
```

---

Better options on linux systems is to create a symbolic link.

```
ln -s "/Path /To A/File" /tmp/file
```

& then in argument file, use `-Dargument1="/tmp/file"`
Use this approach, if there is only one file `"/Path /To A/File"` in question.

---

Another approach is using `mount --bind`

```
mkdir /tmp/myfiles && mount --bind "/Path /To A" /tmp/myfiles
```

& then in argument file, use `-Dargument1="/tmp/myfiles/File"`
This approach would mount `"/Path /To A"` to  `/tmp/myfiles`. All the files & directory structure in it will be retained.

Answer (score 0):

The script worked when used with the command eval, which preserves quotes and it didn't add any additional single quotes.

```
  D_ARG=`(tr '\r\n' ' ' < argument.dat)
 \#executing java code by passing above argument
  eval java ${D_ARG} TestProgram
```